# Datatables filter ignore special characters with html data

Tags: filter, datatables, special-characters, html-dataset

I'm having some trouble initializing a Datatables search filter to ignore special characters.  I'm using the technique from the datatables
[accent neutralise plugin.](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise)

It works properly with string data, but not with html data in the table.  My test case uses names with variations of the letter **u** (with or without an umlaut)... **u, ü, U, Ü**  I would like for the filter to show results for the name "**tuv**", regardless of capitalization or the umlaut on u.

**STRING example:**
search for "tuv" finds all cases, regardless of accents... but "name" column sort is not functioning correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/hdq8bLqn/

**HTML example:**
search for "tuv" finds only unaccented matches.. but "name" column sort functions correctly.
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/cj2s501L/

Here is the initialization code:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.string = function(data) {
  return !data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
    data
    .replace(/έ/g, 'ε')
    .replace(/ύ/g, 'υ')
    .replace(/ό/g, 'ο')
    .replace(/ώ/g, 'ω')
    .replace(/ά/g, 'α')
    .replace(/ί/g, 'ι')
    .replace(/ή/g, 'η')
    .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
    .replace(/[áÁ]/g, 'a')
    .replace(/[éÉ]/g, 'e')
    .replace(/[íÍ]/g, 'i')
    .replace(/[óÓ]/g, 'o')
    .replace(/[úÚ]/g, 'u')
    .replace(/[üÜ]/g, 'u')
    .replace(/ê/g, 'e')
    .replace(/î/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ô/g, 'o')
    .replace(/è/g, 'e')
    .replace(/ï/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ã/g, 'a')
    .replace(/õ/g, 'o')
    .replace(/ç/g, 'c')
    .replace(/ì/g, 'i') :
    data;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
  // Remove accented character from search input as well
  $('#example_filter input').keyup(function() {
    oTable
      .search(
        jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.string(this.value)
      )
      .draw();
  });
});
```

I think the [strip html plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/html) could be adapted to address this problem.  I've got it working to replace one special character, but I need to be able to replace several.  The column sorting also works correctly with this method.

https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/ueo8x7up/

```
(function () {
var _div = document.createElement('div');
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.html = function(data) {
    _div.innerHTML = data;
  return _div.textContent ? 
    _div.textContent.replace(/[üÜ]/g, 'u') :
    _div.innerText.replace(/[üÜ]/g, 'u');
};
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "type": "html",
      "targets": '_all'
    }]
  });
});
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Comment: Well, I got some insight into the problem, but not yet a solution.  If you insert `alert(typeof data +  ' ' + data);` as the first line of your function, you'll notice that none of the data in the Name column get passed to the function when you have a link in it.  I'm going to say that this is because the function only accepts string input, and your link type isn't a string.  I don't quite understand what Allan Jardine did with `jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.string`, but I suspect that's what needs modification, such that it will include links in the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, by adapting the [Datatables strip html plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/html) to replace a chain of special characters in the html.

The jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.**html** method resolved the problems faced when tables contain html data that could not be resolved with the  jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.**string** method used in the [Datatables accent neutralise plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise).

https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/xjzuahrt/1/

```
(function() {
  var _div = document.createElement('div');
  jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.html = function(data) {
    _div.innerHTML = data;
    return _div.textContent ?
      _div.textContent
        .replace(/[áÁàÀâÂäÄãÃåÅæÆ]/g, 'a')
        .replace(/[çÇ]/g, 'c')
        .replace(/[éÉèÈêÊëË]/g, 'e')
        .replace(/[íÍìÌîÎïÏîĩĨĬĭ]/g, 'i')
        .replace(/[ñÑ]/g, 'n')
        .replace(/[óÓòÒôÔöÖœŒ]/g, 'o')
        .replace(/[ß]/g, 's')
        .replace(/[úÚùÙûÛüÜ]/g, 'u')
        .replace(/[ýÝŷŶŸÿ]/g, 'n') :
      _div.innerText
        .replace(/[áÁàÀâÂäÄãÃåÅæÆ]/g, 'a')
        .replace(/[çÇ]/g, 'c')
        .replace(/[éÉèÈêÊëË]/g, 'e')
        .replace(/[íÍìÌîÎïÏîĩĨĬĭ]/g, 'i')
        .replace(/[ñÑ]/g, 'n')
        .replace(/[óÓòÒôÔöÖœŒ]/g, 'o')
        .replace(/[ß]/g, 's')
        .replace(/[úÚùÙûÛüÜ]/g, 'u')
        .replace(/[ýÝŷŶŸÿ]/g, 'n');
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "type": "html",
      "targets": '_all'
    }]
  });
 // Remove accented character from search input as well
    $('#example_filter input[type=search]').keyup( function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
        table.search(
            jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.html(this.value)
        ).draw();
    } );
});
```